# WPF - Listview data binding to web socket data too slow

Tags: c#, wpf, api, mvvm, data-binding

I load about 190 items from a web socket and display them in a listview but the update on the data is too slow and not in synchrony with the real data. I tried with one item and it works perfectly. Is there a more efficient way to bind the data to the ObservableCollection? Should I try with virtualization? Or any other suggestions to make the code work as expected? Here is my code

The Models:

```
 public class WSFuturesResponse
    {
        public string channel { get; set; }
        public string market { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public WSFuturesData data { get; set; } = new WSFuturesData();

    }
    public class WSFuturesData
    {
        public double? bid { get; set; }
        public double? ask { get; set; }
        public double? bidSize { get; set; }
        public double? askSize { get; set; }
        public double? last { get; set; }
        public double? time { get; set; }
    }

 public class Tickers
    {
        public string Market { get; set; }

        public double? Price { get; set; }

        public Tickers(string market)
        {
            Market = market;
        }
    }
 public class ApiFuturesData
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
 public class ApiFuturesResponse
    {
        public bool success { get; set; }
        public List<ApiFuturesData> result { get; set; }
    }
```

The ViewModel

```
public class Ticker : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        protected string url = "wss://ftx.com/ws/";

        protected WebSocket _webSocketClient;

        public Action OnWebSocketConnect;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private WSFuturesResponse _futuresResponse;

        public List<Tickers> ListTickers = new List<Tickers>();

        public WSFuturesResponse FuturesResponse
        {
            get
            {
                return _futuresResponse;
            }
            set
            {
                _futuresResponse = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FuturesResponse");

                // Use the dispatcher to avoid  System.NotSupportedException
                App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate
                {
                    Tickers.Clear();
                    foreach (var future in ListTickers)
                    {
                        if (future.Market == FuturesResponse.market)
                        {
                            future.Price = FuturesResponse.data.last;
                        }
                        Tickers.Add(future);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Tickers> Tickers { get; set; }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }


        public Ticker()
        {
            Tickers = new ObservableCollection<Tickers>();
            StartWebSocket();
        }

        public void StartWebSocket()
        {
            Client client = new Client("firstkey", "secondkey");
            FtxRestApi api = new FtxRestApi(client);
            StartConnection(this, client, api);

        }

        private async void StartConnection(Ticker wsApi, Client client, FtxRestApi api)
        {
            // get all futures data from the API
            var futures = await api.GetAllFuturesAsync();
            // parse the data
            ApiFuturesResponse all_futures = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiFuturesResponse>(futures);

            wsApi.OnWebSocketConnect += () =>
            {
                wsApi.SendCommand(FtxWebSocketRequestGenerator.GetAuthRequest(client));
                foreach (ApiFuturesData future in all_futures.result)
                {
                    if (future.name.Contains("PERP"))
                    {
                        // add the name to the list and use it to subscribe to the channel
                        ListTickers.Add(new Tickers(future.name));
                        wsApi.SendCommand(FtxWebSocketRequestGenerator.GetSubscribeRequest("ticker", future.name));
                    }
                }
            };

            await wsApi.Connect();
        }

 public void WebsocketOnMessageReceive(object o, MessageReceivedEventArgs messageReceivedEventArgs)
        {
            FuturesResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WSFuturesResponse>(messageReceivedEventArgs.Message);
        }
```

And the XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="FTXTradingClient.Views.TickerView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:FTXTradingClient.ViewModel"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FTXTradingClient.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="FTX Trading Client" Height="850" Width="1200">
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:Ticker x:Key="vm"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource vm}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListView Grid.Row="2"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Tickers}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Market}"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Price}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to reset the `Tickers` property instead of first clearing all items in it and then add the new ones back:

```
public WSFuturesResponse FuturesResponse
{
    get
    {
        return _futuresResponse;
    }
    set
    {
        _futuresResponse = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("FuturesResponse");

        foreach (var future in ListTickers)
        {
            if (future.Market == FuturesResponse.market)
            {
                future.Price = FuturesResponse.data.last;
            }
        }

        // Use the dispatcher to avoid  System.NotSupportedException
        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate
        {
            Tickers = new ObservableCollection<Tickers>(ListTickers);
        });
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<Tickers> _tickers;
public ObservableCollection<Tickers> Tickers
{
    get { return _tickers; }
    set { _tickers = value; OnPropertyChanged("Tickers"); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mm8, it worked. First I changed the code as you have suggested but it was still laggy but the change also allowed me to remove the dispatcher and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: I binded the items as you said, the only thing I removed from your answer is the dispatcher. As I said in my previos comment the data is accurate and no longer laggy. But when I go with the mouse over the list the highlighting flickers. I think it is because on every new property change I create a new ObservableCollection, so the list view goes from being full to being empty(flickering) to being full again. What can I do to avoid that?

Comment: You should obviously not create a new collection to frequently but please ask a new question if you have another issue.